# How to concat key and value from dictionary to list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate key and value from a dictionary, and I would like to put them in a sublist according to the key; but I do not succeed. So far what I have (working on Python 2.7):

I managed to concatenate the key and values, but not to split them in different sublists.

```
dict = {'v1':[1, 2, 3], 'v2': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

concat = []
for key in dict.keys():
    vals = dict [key]
    for v in vals:
        concat.append(str(key + '_' + str(v)))
```

I get:

```
 ['v1_1', 'v1_2', 'v1_3', 'v2_1', 'v2_2', 'v2_3', 'v2_4']
```

but I would like:

```
[['v1_1', 'v1_2', 'v1_3'], ['v2_1', 'v2_2', 'v2_3', 'v2_4']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict = {'v1':[1, 2, 3], 'v2': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
res=[]
for key in dict.keys():
    vals = dict [key]
    res.append([ key+'_'+str(v) for v in vals])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this list comprehension. Python 3.6+.

```
>>> [[ f'{k}_{x}' for x in dict[k] ] for k in dict]
[['v1_1', 'v1_2', 'v1_3'], ['v2_1', 'v2_2', 'v2_3', 'v2_4']]
```

Or for Python < 3.6.

```
>>> [[ '%s_%d' % (k,x)  for x in d[k] ] for k in d]
[['v1_1', 'v1_2', 'v1_3'], ['v2_1', 'v2_2', 'v2_3', 'v2_4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending to the same list on both levels of your `for` loop. Change it to

```py
for key in dict.keys():
    sublist = []
    vals = dict [key]
    for v in vals:
        sublist.append(str(key + '_' + str(v)))
    concat.append(sublist)
```